# Записать значение в середину файла. Bash

Tags: linux, регулярные-выражения, bash, sed

Есть значение приватного ключа, например: 123456

Есть файл test.txt вида

```
много текста
.
.
.
PrivateKey = <insert private_key>
.
.
.
много текста
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как используя linux команды сделать так, чтоб файл test.txt имел вид?

```
много текста
.
.
.
PrivateKey = 123456
.
.
.
много текста
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -i.bak '/^PrivateKey =/s/<insert private_key>/123456/' ./path/to/conf.conf
```

Эта команда откроет файл `./path/to/conf.conf`, найдет `PrivateKey =` и на этой строке заменит `<insert private_key>` на `123456`. Сохранит старый файл по адресу `./path/to/conf.conf.bak`, и исправленный вариант сохранит по исходному адресу `./path/to/conf.conf`.